# getJSON call succeeds but still throws 500 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a getJSON() call that accesses a view that returns some data. The call works and the data is retrieved but despite this I am still getting a 500 error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

MultiValueDictKeyError at /album_ajax/
"Key u'reid' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/album_ajax/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
Python Path: ['/Users/Santi/programming/feastfm', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

I've looked on SO and tried asking around on IRC but haven't been able to figure out why I'm getting this error. The syntax of the view/call is copied directly from: http://lethain.com/two-faced-django-part-5-jquery-ajax/

views.py

```
def get_album_tracks(request):
    get = request.GET.copy()
    reid = get["reid"]
    url = "http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/"+reid+"?fmt=json&inc=artist-credits+recordings"
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    api_results = json.load(data)
    tracks = []
    for entry in api_results['media']:
        for track in entry['tracks']:
            artist = track['artist-credit'][0]['name']
            title = track['title']
            tracks.append({'artist':artist, 'title':title})
    # results = {'reid':reid, 'tracks':tracks}
    results = {'test':"is this working?", "reid":reid, 'tracks':tracks}
    return_json = simplejson.dumps(results)
    return HttpResponse(return_json, mimetype='application/json')
```

the getJSON() call

```
$.getJSON("/album_ajax/", {"reid": reid}, function(json){
        if(json['tracks']){
            //alert("json?: " + json["tracks"]+" reid: "+json['reid']);
            // var album = $('data-reid ='+)
            for(var i=0; i<json['tracks'].length; i++){
                //console.log(json['tracks'][i]['title'])
                var artist = json['tracks'][i]['artist']
                var title = json['tracks'][i]['title']
                $(ul).append("<li class = 'album-track track' data-artist = '"+escape(artist) +"' data-title ='" + escape(title) +"'>"+artist +" - "+ title+"</li>");
            }

        }
        else{
            alert('no results')
        }
        })
```

I don't understand why am I getting both a 500 error and having the success function run.

**EDIT**

I put a print statement inside my view and it looks like the view function is being called twice, once with an empty QueryDict and once with a QueryDict containing the reid variable:

```
album_tracks was just called
<QueryDict: {}>
album_tracks was just called
<QueryDict: {u'reid': [u'0447570d-4804-49f1-9396-d71ddd8f59c4']}>
```

I am still not sure where in the code the call is made twice.

**EDIT 2**

Including the entire function which has the getJSON() call

```
$('.album').click(function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    // if(!$target.is("ul"))
    if(!$target.is("div")) //magic happens here!!
        {
            return;
        }
    if($(this).children("li").length >= 1){
        $(this).children("li").toggle();
    }
    else{
        var reid = $(this).data('reid');
        ul = this;
        var data = {"reid": reid};
        // var args = { type:"GET", url:"/album/", data:data, complete:done };
        // $.ajax(args);
        $.getJSON("/album_ajax/", data, function(json){
        if(json['tracks']){
            //alert("json?: " + json["tracks"]+" reid: "+json['reid']);
            // var album = $('data-reid ='+)
            for(var i=0; i<json['tracks'].length; i++){
                //console.log(json['tracks'][i]['title'])
                var artist = json['tracks'][i]['artist']
                var title = json['tracks'][i]['title']
                $(ul).append("<li class = 'album-track track' data-artist = '"+escape(artist) +"' data-title ='" + escape(title) +"'>"+artist +" - "+ title+"</li>");
            }

        }


        else{
            alert('no results')
        }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure why you are getting data back but the problem seems to be accessing the reid param from GET. Can you check to make sure that param is there? In the JS, make sure the value is non-null.

Comment: It's not null, otherwise it wouldn't be able to return any data bc it uses the parameter to do an API lookup.

It seems weird that problem is in accessing the parameter when it clearly is able to access it, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: could you show the code where you call getJson?

Comment: updated to show more code

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint or console.log in your event handler to see if it is somehow being called twice?

Comment: It is showing that the element is clicked once, where the reid shows a value of undefined, and then the element is clicked a second time, where the reid shows the appropriate value and the call succeeds. I don't know why the event handler is firing twice.

Comment: Could you post the html snippet that includes the .album class?

Comment: I just caught the problem, there are two elements of class album, one of them has a data-reid attribute and the other doesn't. One is a div inside the other so when I click on the div, they both fire. Thanks to @JesseVogt for telling me to look at the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had multiple elements with the class, one of which had the data-attribute needed to make the ajax call work, the other which did not. They were both firing, one was failing and the other was succeeding.

Thanks to @jesse-vogt for telling me to look for the .album class in the html code.